# Cimplicity Screen - one object/button that is dependent on hundreds of points

Tags: plc

So I have created a huge screen that essentially just shows the robot status for every robot in this factory (individually)… At the very end of the project, they decided they want one object on the screen that blinks if any of the 300 robots fault. I am trying to think of a way to make this work. Maybe a global script of some kind? Problem is, I do not do much scripting in Cimplicity, so any help is appreciated.

All the points that are currently used on this screen (to indicate a fault) have very similar names… as in, the beginning is the same… so I was thinking of a script that could maybe recognize if a bit is high based on PART of it's string name characteristic. The end will change a little each time, but I am sure there is a way to only look for part of a string and negate the rest. If the end has to be hard coded, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Python script in Cimplicity](https://www.ge.com/digital/documentation/cimplicity/version2022/oxy_ex-2/basic_control_engine_and_scripting/topics/g_cimplicity_basic_control_engine_and_scripting_python_overview.html).

I will not go into detail on the use of python in Cimplicity, which is well described in the documentation indicated above.

Here's an example of what can be done... note that I don't have a way to test it and, of course, this will work if the name of your robots in the declaration follows the format `Robot_1`, `Robot_2`, `Robot_3` ... `Robot_10` ... `Robot_300` and it also depends on the Name and the Type of the fault variable... as you didn't define it, I imagine it can be an integer, with ZERO indicating no error. But if you use something other than that, you can easily change it.

```py
import cimplicity

(...)

OneRobotWithFault = False

# Here you get the values and check for fault
for i in range(0, 300):
    pointName = f'MyFactory.Robot_{i}.FaultCode'
    robotFaultCode = cimplicity.point_get(pointName)

    if robotFaultCode > 0:
        OneRobotWithFault = True
        break

# Set the status to the variable "WeHaveRobotWithFault"
cimplicity.point_set("WeHaveRobotWithFault", OneRobotWithFault)
```